# Obtaining Client Certificate from tcp-streams (or tls) Package in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ssl, gemini

I'm working on implementing a Gemini server framework (yes, I'm aware of the `gemini-server` package, but mine doesn't need to link against OpenSSL).

Everything's working as it should with one exception: when the client connects with a certificate, that certificate isn't being passed on to my handler.  Admittedly, I had to resort to some unconventional means to try to obtain it, as the `tcp-streams` package I'm using didn't seem to natively support doing that.

My code is [on Codeberg](https://codeberg.org/jlamothe/gemcap), with my current attempts to fix it under the `certfix` branch.

The most pertinent functions are likely `runGemCapsule`, `listenLoop` and `adjustServerParams` (all in the `Network.Gemini.Capsule` module).

Any thoughts about what might be going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't being passed" ? Does `certHook` just not run at all, or does it run with unexpected arguments?

Comment: It's actually not getting run at all.  I tried throwing some `putStrLn`s in there for debugging purposes.